# Turn cv2's numpy array to be the same as reading binary of an image?

Tags: python, opencv

Is there any way to turn the numpy array representation of an image to be the same as the reading binary(rb) of a file, So that code will work.

```
cv_img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
# Some code here related to the cv_img var...
img = open("image.jpg", 'rb').read()
print(cv_img == img) # So that will be true.
```

I want that because I don't want to have to save the image to be able to get that

open("image.jpg", 'rb').read() output.

Thank you in advance for answering I am pretty new here so I am open to criticism about the way I ask questions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is No. What you get from `open("image.jpg", 'rb').read()` is 1-dimensional array of bytes of a JPEG encoded image. `cv2.imread()`gives you 3-dimensional (width x height x one channel each for blue, green, and red) array of 8-bit values. A one-dimensional array and a three dimensional array aren't directly comparable, and even if they were, the one-dimensional array contains an encoding that has been decoded to form the three-dimensional array.